# Condicionar sumas de un select

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla con la siguiente estructura:

```
codigo / periodo / signo / importe
```

Quiero obtener lo siguiente:

```
codigo / saldo_anterior / cargo_actual / abono_actual / saldo
```

El campo período es integer (AAAAMM)
Si por ejemplo estoy en el mes de noviembre, período sería 201711.
El Saldo_Anterior considera los registros que tienen el período hasta 201710.
El Cargo_Actual y Abono_Actual son del período=201711.
El Cargo y Abono son los importes que se obtienen del signo: "+" = cargo; "-" = abono.
Cómo condiciono lo del período en el select que hace esto de manera genérica?

```
codigo / cargo / abono / saldo
```

Este es el select:

```
SELECT  codigo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) cargo,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) abono,
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) saldo
FROM tabla
GROUP BY codigo
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '+' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) - 
       SUM(CASE WHEN signo = '-' THEN importe ELSE 0 END) <> 0;
```

La estructura de la tabla:

```
ID  codigo  periodo signo   importe
4521    100 20179   +   200.00
4522    200 20179   -   80.00
4523    300 20179   -   70.00
4525    100 201710  +   250.00
4526    200 201710  +   120.00
4527    300 201710  +   350.00
4528    100 201710  -   100.00
4529    300 201710  -   15.00
4530    200 201711  +   170.00
4531    300 201711  +   80.00
4532    500 201711  +   300.00
4533    100 201711  -   110.00
4534    200 201711  -   150.00
4535    300 201711  -   170.00
```

El calculo de saldo_anterior (en este caso) debe ser hasta el periodo 201710 y Luego, cargo actual, abono actual son del periodo 201711. El saldo es la diferencia.

Comment: Y el cargo del presente mes, qué implica? Tiene alguna importancia el cargo del mes anterior en el saldo del mes anterior?

Comment: qué forma y significado tiene el código? No debieras agrupar por periodo?

Comment: El resultado se ordena por código.

Comment: podrías poner un extracto de `select * from tabla` para entender un poco más?

Comment: El código vendría siendo entonces como un número de cliente?

Comment: toda aclaracion debe ir en la pregunta. usa el boton [edit] para agregar la informacion en ella...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no debería ser muy complicado, pero se vuelve complejo exclusivamente por cómo estás guardando el `periodo`. Al ser `int` en formato `YYYYMM`, hace que para calcular el período anterior, tienes que concatenarle un `01`, luego convertirlo en fecha, luego restarle un mes, y luego volver a convertirlo a número.

Sería algo así:

```
SELECT  codigo,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '+' 
                AND t1.periodo = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t2.MaxPeriodo,'01'),'%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y%m') 
                THEN importe 
            ELSE 0 END) - 
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '-' 
                AND t1.periodo = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t2.MaxPeriodo,'01'),'%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y%m') 
                THEN importe 
                ELSE 0 
            END) saldo_anterior,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '+' 
                AND t1.periodo = t2.MaxPeriodo
                THEN importe 
                ELSE 0 
            END) cargo_actual,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '-' 
                AND t1.periodo = t2.MaxPeriodo
                THEN importe 
                ELSE 0 
            END) abono_actual,
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '+' 
                AND t1.periodo = t2.MaxPeriodo
                THEN importe 
                ELSE 0 
            END) -
        SUM(CASE 
                WHEN signo = '-' 
                AND t1.periodo = t2.MaxPeriodo
                THEN importe 
                ELSE 0 
            END) saldo_actual
FROM tabla t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(periodo) MaxPeriodo
            FROM tabla) t2
WHERE t1.periodo IN (t2.MaxPeriodo,DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t2.MaxPeriodo,'01'),'%Y%m%d') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH,'%Y%m'))
GROUP BY codigo
;
```

Comment: El Período debe incluir el día?, los periodos que manejo están en integer y son: 20171 (Enero), 20172 (febrero)... 201711 (noviembre).

Comment: @Piropeator no debe incluir el día, pero sí para convertirlo a fecha. Ahora, pensé que el formato en que estabas guardando el período era `AAAAMM`, con dos dígitos para el mes (201701), si no es así, entonces es una complicación extra y en este momento no podría reescribir mi respuesta

Comment: o sea que un order por esa columna, anda mal??? @Piropeator.. esto es codigo productivo???

Comment: @gbianchi no entiendo tu pregunta. El select que puse calcula los saldos generales. Pero yo necesito un saldo parcial al período anterior. Pensé que se podría hacer en un solo select. Mi otra opción es crear una vista y llenar allí los valores.

Comment: @Piropeator la pregunta de gbianchi es por el diseño de guardar el periodo en formato AAAAM para meses de enero a septiembre y AAAAMM para octubre a diciembre

Comment: @Lamak Sí, tienen razón, no es óptimo. Voy a modificar eso. Pero igual mencionaste que la complicación era la forma en cómo guardo el período. Podrías recomendarme una forma más óptima?

Comment: no, solucionandolo a guardarlos todos con el mismo formato, se arregla el problema @Piropeator

Comment: @Piropeator la verdad es que yo no uso mysql, por lo que no sabría aconsejarte la mejor forma en este caso. La idea es evitar transformaciones tan complicadas para obtener por ejemplo el período anterior